# Earning reputation without reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

How do you earn reputation when trying to start on Stack Overflow?
Typically, I'm programming in C# at work, using and consuming SO threads several times a day.

I'd be able to up/down many answers each time I use SO but can't without reputation.
Unfortunately I won't ask new questions since almost anything I wonder has been answered already.
And I won't answer questions since almost anything I would answer has been told already.

I really want to participate but don't really know how.
Please tell me how to do it, old lads!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can suggest edits. Edit posts that need more than minor improvment. If your suggested edit gets approved by 3 reviewers then you get 2 rep for that.

Do that 7 times and you have 15 rep to upvote.

And BTW there are always questions you can answer that haven't been answered yet.

Comment: Answering old questions wont get you rep though. At least not in the short run. Would be still usefull though.